# Cordova Windows build 'No valid MSBuild was detected for the selected target'

Tags: windows, visual-studio, cordova, msbuild

I'm trying to build my cordova application on Windows 10 but it fails because of the selected path i guess. I have Visual Studio 2017 installed and want to select the msbuild path at: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin but the process always uses C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin for building the application.
I am not sure what the problem exactly is if the path is the problem or are there any problems with versions. The application wasn't developed by me so I'm not really familiar with where and why my problem is caused.

I have already tried to change my Windows path variable but it does not affect the build process. Also I switched from Visual Studio 2019 to 2017 because cordova build is not supported anymore.

**My CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj file:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputPath>build\windows\$(Configuration)\$(Platform)\win10\</OutputPath>
        <IntermediateOutputPath>build\windows\bld\</IntermediateOutputPath>
        <AppxPackageSigningEnabled>true</AppxPackageSigningEnabled>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
        <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|AnyCPU">
            <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
            <Platform>AnyCPU</Platform>
        </ProjectConfiguration>
        <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|ARM">
            <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
            <Platform>ARM</Platform>
        </ProjectConfiguration>
        <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|x64">
            <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
            <Platform>x64</Platform>
        </ProjectConfiguration>
        <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|x86">
            <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
            <Platform>x86</Platform>
        </ProjectConfiguration>
        <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|AnyCPU">
            <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
            <Platform>AnyCPU</Platform>
        </ProjectConfiguration>
        <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|ARM">
            <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
            <Platform>ARM</Platform>
            <UseDotNetNativeToolchain>true</UseDotNetNativeToolchain>
        </ProjectConfiguration>
        <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|x64">
            <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
            <Platform>x64</Platform>
            <UseDotNetNativeToolchain>true</UseDotNetNativeToolchain>
        </ProjectConfiguration>
        <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|x86">
            <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
            <Platform>x86</Platform>
            <UseDotNetNativeToolchain>true</UseDotNetNativeToolchain>
        </ProjectConfiguration>
    </ItemGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
        <ProjectGuid>f9b0ae20-c21c-42b9-9c4e-d8k328b4509e</ProjectGuid>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
        <UseDotNetNativeToolchain>true</UseDotNetNativeToolchain>
        <EnableDotNetNativeCompatibleProfile>true</EnableDotNetNativeCompatibleProfile>
        <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(CordovaBundlePlatforms)' != ''" Label="CordovaBuildParameters">
        <AppxBundle>Always</AppxBundle>
        <AppxBundlePlatforms>$(CordovaBundlePlatforms)</AppxBundlePlatforms>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Import Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" />
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '' or '$(VisualStudioVersion)' &lt; '14.0'">
        <VisualStudioVersion>14.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\$(WMSJSProjectDirectory)\Microsoft.VisualStudio.$(WMSJSProject).Default.props" />
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\$(WMSJSProjectDirectory)\Microsoft.VisualStudio.$(WMSJSProject).props" />
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetPlatformIdentifier>UAP</TargetPlatformIdentifier>
        <TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
        <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.16299.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
        <MinimumVisualStudioVersion>14.0</MinimumVisualStudioVersion>
        <UapDefaultAssetScale>100</UapDefaultAssetScale>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' &lt; '14.0'">
        <TargetPlatformVersion>10.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
        <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <AppxManifest Include="package.windows10.appxmanifest">
            <SubType>Designer</SubType>
        </AppxManifest>
    </ItemGroup>
    <Import Label="Shared" Project="CordovaApp.projitems" />
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\$(WMSJSProjectDirectory)\Microsoft.VisualStudio.$(WMSJSProject).targets" />
    <Target AfterTargets="ResolveAssemblyReferences" BeforeTargets="AfterResolveReferences" Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'AnyCPU'" Name="DetectMangedWinMDWithAnyCpu">
        <Error Condition="'%(_ResolveAssemblyReferenceResolvedFiles.WinMDFile)' == 'true' AND '%(_ResolveAssemblyReferenceResolvedFiles.WinMDFileType)' == 'Managed'" Text="The following component requires .NET Native compilation which is not available when targeting 'Windows10' and 'AnyCPU'. Consider changing the targeted processor architecture to one of the following: 'x86, x64, ARM' (if you are using command line this could be done by adding '--archs' parameter, for example: 'cordova build windows --archs=x64'). %(_ResolveAssemblyReferenceResolvedFiles.Identity)" />
    </Target>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <PreBuildEvent>node "$(ProjectDir)\\cordova\\prebuild-10.js"</PreBuildEvent>
        <DisableFastUpToDateCheck>true</DisableFastUpToDateCheck>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

**This is my console output:**

```
Building project: C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop\output-win\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj
        Configuration : debug
        Platform      : x86
        Buildflags    : /p:CordovaBundlePlatforms=x86
        MSBuildTools  : C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin
buildProject spawn: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild [ 'C:\\Users\\Thomas\\Desktop\\output-win\\platforms\\windows\\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj',  
  '/clp:NoSummary;NoItemAndPropertyList;Verbosity=minimal',
  '/nologo',
  '/p:Configuration=debug',
  '/p:Platform=x86',
  '/p:CordovaBundlePlatforms=x86' ] { stdio: 'inherit' }
C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop\output-win\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj(61,5): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Mi 
crosoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio..Default.props" was not found. Make sure that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct.  
and the file exists on the disk.
No valid MSBuild was detected for the selected target: Error: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe: Command failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: What's the result if you use Developer command prompt for VS2017 to build? Try changing the Toolsversion to 15.0.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i solved it in an other way but by using the Developer command prompt the build worked and finished with the `cordova build windows' command too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it own my own. 
With the `>cordova prepare` command, which generates the windows platform including .sln file for Visual Studio and .jsproj files I changed my directory to `\app\platforms\windows` where the CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj is located. After executing `>MSBuild CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj` i got an other error message that was much clearer and after fixing i got my finished build.

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for your sharing and please mark your reply as answer and that will help other community members who easier search this useful information. See [can I answer...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) it just a reminder :)

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for your sharing and you can consider marking it as answer which indicated this issue is resolved. It will also help other community members to easier search this useful information. See [answer own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer):)